# Regex pattern to capture a section of string

Tags: regex

I want to capture a block of text between interface and the exclamation point (!) below

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  description access port
  switchport access vlan 100
  no logging event link-status
  authentication periodic
!
```

can someone look and help to see what I did wrong please? thank you

I use the regex pattern `(?sm)^interface\sgigabitethernet\d\/\d\/\d\r\n.*!$` and it works on the regextester web site

Below is my script

```
$folder = "C:\my_config_files"
$files = Get-ChildItem $Folder\*.txt
function Get-Interfaces($pattern){
  $interface = @()
  foreach($file in $files)
  $Config=Get-Content $file -raw
  $str_interface = $Config |Select-String $pattern
 if($str_interface){
  $interface += New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Interface'=$Str_interface}
  }
 else{ 
  $interface += New-Object PSObject -Property @{'Interface'="Not Found"}
 }
  }
  $interface | Select 'Interface' | Export-CSV c:\My_Configs\Interfaces.csv
 }

find Get-Interfaces "(?smi)^interface\s+gigabitethernet\d/\d/\d\r\n.*?^!$"
```

Comment: Yes, in most cases, it is because you did not read in the file with `-Raw`. Try adding that and using `(?smi)^interface\s+gigabitethernet\d/\d/\d\r\n.*?^!$`

Comment: I tried your solution as below foreach($file in $file) {$config = get-content $file -raw $match = $config | select-string -pattern "(?smi)^interface\s+gigabitethernet\d\/\d\/\d\r\n.*?^!$" but it didn't  match and no output.

Comment: `foreach ($file in $file)` sounds confusing. Please post the code in the question.

Comment: $folder = "C:\Config_Files"

Comment: I do not see your actual file contents. Does `"(?smi)^interface\s+gigabitethernet\d/\d/\d\r\n.*?^!\r?$"` work?

Comment: unfortunately not yet. If I just use "(?smi)^interface\s+GigabitEthernet.*) then it outputs all the interfaces as expected

Comment: unfortunately not yet. If I just use "(?smi)^interface\s+GigabitEthernet\d\/\d\/\d.*" then it outputs all the interfaces as expected.  When I tested this regex "(?smi)^interface\s+GigabitEthernet\d\/\d\/\d.*"  to add \r\n to see if it see the carriage return and a newline, then it didn't output anything

Comment: Try `"(?smi)^interface\s+gigabitethernet\d/\d/\d\r?\n.*?^!\r?$"` then

Answer (score 0):

This might work, for just reading the lines between interface Gigabit... and !:

```
^interface\sGigabitEthernet[^\n]+\n([^!]+)\n!$
```

[playground](https://regex101.com/r/I0D55H/1)

Comment: yes it worked on the regex tester online but when I ran it with my powershell script it didn't give me any output